# How to get NTC resistor's temperature vs resistor curve?

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, thermistor

I have a thermistor [MF52203](https://www.cantherm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cantherm_mf52_1.pdf) whose rated resistance is 20k. However, the datasheet seems like not providing the temperature vs resistor curve. Without this curve, how can I get the corresponding resistance for a specific temperature, like 40℃？

Comment: https://www.ametherm.com/thermistor/ntc-thermistor-beta

Comment: or google "thermistor B value" and find numerous sites explaining how the "B value" specifies the thermal response. Unfortunately, Cantherm's FAQ that should have this information ([here](https://www.cantherm.com/faq/)) is missing the actual formulas.

Comment: Looking further, they do provide the information [here](https://www.cantherm.com/rt-characteristics/).

Answer (score 1):

[image].

The data is available from their website here:. 
https://www.cantherm.com/rt-characteristics/

This is at coarse level **except the needed 20k**. When you need at 20k level, you can use the equations.

---

Depending on the complete part number of the part you are using, you can select Beta:
[image]

Comment: For example, \$B=4050\:\text{K}\$ corresponds to a work function of \$0.349\:\text{eV}\$ (not shown in the chart.)

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasted from the link below:

[image]

https://www.ametherm.com/thermistor/ntc-thermistor-beta

Comment: This whole deal can be derived from "fair dice" in elementary probability theory. (Which reaches back to Boltzmann -- or, my preference, later on by Shannon.) The Boltzmann factor tells all here -- just a ratio of probabilities. Note that I'm talking about dice, with quantum states. In classical thermodynamics this is more difficult to follow. But once you recognize the quantum nature of states, the whole thing just falls out of elementary probability. Including, it turns out, thermistor behavior. I could derive this from first principles. But I'd probably annoy someone. (\$\beta\$=Eg/k.)